# How to manage test data when tests are running in parallel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parallel-processing

I am working on improving my automated functional tests to run in parallel to decrease the test suite run time. The problem that I am having is understanding how to manage my test data when the tests are running in parallel.

More specifically, when the tests run consecutively, I use a single user to login to the application without a problem. However, this does not work when trying to run multiple tests with that user and trying to login. I have other users that I can use to login. My question is how can I manage these users so that 1 test uses 1 unique user? And no other test touches that user until he is free.

If you could provide some pseudocode or a code sample, it would really help.

Thanks in advance :)

After feedback from @grafito, this is the solution that I came up with. Seems to be fully working. When all users are Connected, we get stuck in a loop until one is available.

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
[Category("ParallelTest2")]
public class ParallelTestingExampleV2_A : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Test1 has user {AvailableUser.UserName}");
        Thread.Sleep(50000);
        Trace.WriteLine($"Test1 sleeping for 50000ms so one user is Connected.");
    }
}
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
[Category("ParallelTest2")]
public class ParallelTestingExampleV2_B : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Test2 has user {AvailableUser.UserName}");
    }
}
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
[Category("ParallelTest2")]
public class ParallelTestingExampleV2_C : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Test3 has user {AvailableUser.UserName}");
    }
}

[SetUpFixture]
public class TestFixtureForTestsNamespace
{
    public static ListOfUsers ListOfAllPossibleUsers;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAllTestsAreExecutedInSomeNamespace()
    {
        GetPoolOfUsers();
    }

    private static void GetPoolOfUsers()
    {
        var oneUser = new User
        {
            UserName = "a",
            Password = "a"
        };

        var secondUser = new User
        {
            UserName = "b",
            Password = "b"
        };
        ListOfAllPossibleUsers = new ListOfUsers() { oneUser, secondUser };
    }
}

public class BaseTest
{
    protected User AvailableUser;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupForEveryTestMethod()
    {
        AvailableUser = TestFixtureForTestsNamespace.ListOfAllPossibleUsers.GetAvailableUser();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDownForEveryTestMethod()
    {
        TestFixtureForTestsNamespace.ListOfAllPossibleUsers.ReleaseUser(AvailableUser);
    }
}



public class User
{
    internal string UserName = "";
    internal string Password = "";
    internal bool Connected;
}

public class ListOfUsers : List<User>
{
    internal void ReleaseUser(User userToBeReleased)
    {
        lock (this) { userToBeReleased.Connected = false; }
    }

    internal User GetAvailableUser()
    {
        User user = null;
        while (user == null)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Count && user == null; i++)
                {
                    if (!this[i].Connected)
                        user = this[i];
                }
                if (user != null)
                    user.Connected = true;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you have tagged unit tests, but seem to be describing integration tests.  The strategies for the two are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pool of users and, when running a "new" test, get a user from the users pool. If all users already connected, wait for a user (released by the end of a terminated test).

```
internal class UserDef 
{
  internal string Login  = "" ; // eventually add password 
  internal bool   Connected = false ;
}

internal class UserDefs : List<UserDef>
{
   internal ReleaseUser(UserDef userdef)
   {
     lock(this) { userdef.Connected=false ; }
   }

   internal UserDef GetAvailableUser() 
   {
     UserDef result=null ;
     while (result==null) 
     {
       lock(this)
       {
         for (int i=0;i<Count && result==null;i++) if (!this[i].Connected) result=this[i] ;
         if (result!=null) result.Connected = true ;
       }
       system.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200) ;
     }  
   return result ;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used your code to finalize my implementation above which I added into my question.

Answer (score 1):

IMO there is no silver bullet solution here - for each application its a different story. I can only provide only a couple of general purpose rules that can help

- Separate the Users - indeed like my colleagues have already said, the same tests should not run with the same user
- Separate by abstractions supported by your application. For example, if your application support Multi-tenancy, do your best to run parallel tests in different tenants. Otherwise the tests can clash when accessing in-memory data structures, changed during the test run
- Having said said that, make sure that creating new user, new tenant and so forth for each test does not introduce a significant overhead, because otherwise your tests will just be too slow
- Separate the persistence layers. For instance, if your application works with some kind of data base, 2 tests running in parallel can change the same rows and columns in the same table so again, they'll clash.
- Tests shouldn't leave the application persistence layers/in-memory data structures in a 'dirty' state. This is correct even for consecutive tests, not only parallel. Unfortunately its not always possible.
- If the last item is really impossible to achieve, use pooling only if there is no other choice. For example if you create a pool of users, at some point of   time tests A & B will run under the same user. If test A made data-structures assigned to the user unusable (left them dirty), then test B probably won't run as expected
- Avoid unnecessary tests. A developer has unit tests, integration tests, functional tests - all are valid tools to check the software. So if something can be covered by Unit test - go for it, otherwise go with integration tests, otherwise go with full-fledged functional tests. It seems that you describe a functional test (like always login-in to the system and so forth). Is it really needed? Isn't it an overhead? Maybe you should try to check the behavior of existing component in an integration test that will run only a part of your application/only a relevant component... I know that this advice is too general and applies not only in a context of your question, but it can implicitly help in designing the correct testing infrastructure for the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Make the tests independent - create a new user for each test!

The "pool" of user comes with complexity and can introduce problems for you. If it is a pain to create a new user for each test, you need to solve that problem. But it will be worth it!

Comment: I love this option and I think that this would be an ideal solution. However, it is the hardest solution by far. The architecture of the application does not easily allow for this. The users are tightly coupled to the data. Only specific users can access specific content. There is no API for me to easily create and delete test users. This would require a large effort from the Development team to make this possible. Although this is my dream haha, it's not going to help me in the short term

Answer (score 0):

After feedback from @grafito, this is the solution that I came up with. Seems to be fully working. When all users are Connected, we get stuck in a loop until one is available.

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
[Category("ParallelTest2")]
public class ParallelTestingExampleV2_A : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Test1 has user {AvailableUser.UserName}");
        Thread.Sleep(50000);
        Trace.WriteLine($"Test1 sleeping for 50000ms so one user is Connected.");
    }
}
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
[Category("ParallelTest2")]
public class ParallelTestingExampleV2_B : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Test2 has user {AvailableUser.UserName}");
    }
}
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
[Category("ParallelTest2")]
public class ParallelTestingExampleV2_C : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Test3 has user {AvailableUser.UserName}");
    }
}

[SetUpFixture]
public class TestFixtureForTestsNamespace
{
    public static ListOfUsers ListOfAllPossibleUsers;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAllTestsAreExecutedInSomeNamespace()
    {
        GetPoolOfUsers();
    }

    private static void GetPoolOfUsers()
    {
        var oneUser = new User
        {
            UserName = "a",
            Password = "a"
        };

        var secondUser = new User
        {
            UserName = "b",
            Password = "b"
        };
        ListOfAllPossibleUsers = new ListOfUsers() { oneUser, secondUser };
    }
}

public class BaseTest
{
    protected User AvailableUser;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupForEveryTestMethod()
    {
        AvailableUser = TestFixtureForTestsNamespace.ListOfAllPossibleUsers.GetAvailableUser();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDownForEveryTestMethod()
    {
        TestFixtureForTestsNamespace.ListOfAllPossibleUsers.ReleaseUser(AvailableUser);
    }
}



public class User
{
    internal string UserName = "";
    internal string Password = "";
    internal bool Connected;
}

public class ListOfUsers : List<User>
{
    internal void ReleaseUser(User userToBeReleased)
    {
        lock (this) { userToBeReleased.Connected = false; }
    }

    internal User GetAvailableUser()
    {
        User user = null;
        while (user == null)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Count && user == null; i++)
                {
                    if (!this[i].Connected)
                        user = this[i];
                }
                if (user != null)
                    user.Connected = true;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

}